# Force weblogic to exclude IncludeTimestamp from generated wsdl

Tags: wsdl, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic12c, wsse

I have an EJB that plays the role of my web service class too. I use Oracle Weblogic 12.1.2 as JavaEE container.
Here is the code of that class:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName="MyService")
@Policy(uri = "Wssp1.2-2007-Https-UsernameToken-Plain.xml", attachToWsdl=true)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyWebServiceBean{
// some web methods ...
}
```

The attached policy and its corresponding wsse tags is properly can be seen in generated WSDL file. However, there is a `IncludeTimestamp` tag in the generated file that forces clients to send Timestamp in their request. As in my environment clients may have different times, I perefer not to force them to send the time! Then I simply omit the `IncludeTimestamp` Tag from the server wsdl and everything goes well after that! But I do not want to handle it by hand. Is there any setting in weblogic 12.1.2 to configure existence of mentioned tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot reading and searching for this matter i found that we should create Custom Policy. Firstly we should find the xml file of the desired policy. Flow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248565/custom-weblogic-web-service-policy/37249846#37249846) post to do so. Then we should edit it and copy the edited version in our classpath and for `@Policy` annotation we should use new address of our xml file! That's it.