# Custom WebLogic Web Service Policy

Tags: weblogic12c, ws-security, policy, wsse, usernametoken

I use Weblogic 12.1.2 as the JavaEE container. I want to use my custom ws-security policy (because weblogic predefined ws-plocies has `IncludeTimestamp` and I want to remove this tag). Therefore I need one of the policies' xml file, for example UsernameToken-Plain.xml to edit it and use it.
Where can I find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24488/message.htm#WSSOV310) they should be located in below path:

> MW_HOME/WL_HOME/server/lib/weblogic.jar. Within weblogic.jar, the
>   policy files are located in /weblogic/wsee/policy/runtime.

However, I was not be able to find the files, finally I found that those files actually are located in `MW_HOME/WL_HOME/modules/features/weblogic.server.merged.jar` and in weblogic.server.merged.jar file: `/weblogic/wsee/policy/runtime/`
I don't know why the documentation is not right, maybe because of the version (I use 12.1.2 and the documentation is for 12.1.1) however I have seen a lot of conflicts in Oracle documentation (Specially in security sections) so far.